# Closing InfoTemplate Programmatically in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to hide a layer on the map like

```
      var point = new esri.geometry.Point(-106.61, 35.1107);
      point = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(point);
      var symbol = new esri.symbol.PictureMarkerSymbol("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Map-Markers-Icons-Demo-PNG/128/Map-Marker-Marker-Outside-Chartreuse.png", 32, 32);
      pointInfoTemplate = new InfoTemplate(); 
      pointInfoTemplate.setTitle("Project Details");
      pointInfoTemplate.setContent('<div>Some Att Here</div> ');
      var graphic = new esri.Graphic(point, symbol).setInfoTemplate(pointInfoTemplate);
      layer1 = new esri.layers.GraphicsLayer();
      layer1.add(graphic);
      map.addLayer(layer1);

$("#hide").on("click", function(){
    layer1.hide();
});
```

which works fine but the `InfoTemplate()` remains in the map (in case of it being opened)

[image]

Comment: What version of the JS API are you on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to have a reference to the [map object](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html) in your event handler (do this using scope binding), but once you do you can do:

```
map.infoWindow.hide();
```